# Preslecting button for user in finance environment

Tags: usability

Im fighting to figure a problem I need to solve in our crypto deposit app we have:

**Problem:**
We want to show the user what is the best amount to deposit/exchange

Our chef leader if pushing to preselect the buttons and add labels to them but I believe that is NOT a good idea to make choices for the users themselves.
Any idea of how to solve this elegantly without pushing on Users too much?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

I would refrain from changing the default selection as it is a dark pattern. Instead of "We want this" you could write "Good deal" or "Popular" or something similar.

Beware though, that it may come of as being cheap as you usually see these kinds of patterns on sketchy comparison shopping websites that want to lure you into buying something that they have been paid to promote.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a subtle hint under (or over) the option?

[image]

This way you are not pushing anything to the users, only hinting at the option you find the best. And it won't interfere with the user's choice.

You can even put an (i) icon next to the text for "more information", if needed.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to financial transactions, require the user to make selections. Instructions are often misunderstood, ignored, or missed altogether. And when the user has more to lose the risk of litigation against the provider is greater. The more actions the user has to make the less liability the provider has.

As far as encouraging larger transactions, what's the benefit to the user? State that along with the selections. If there is no particular benefit to the user—make one.

[image: benefits]